# (AndEngine Multiplayer) Client Get data From Server when connected to a server

Tags: android, andengine, multiplayer

Hi I`m Working On MultyPlayerGame By Using AndEngine Multiplayer Extention And I Need Client Get Some Data From Server When They Connect To a Server

Now How Can I Get Some Data From Server ? I need To Get Some int Or String Data When a Client Connected To a Server

there is Just This Code :

```
// Listener - states when we (as a client) have connected to a server
@Override
public void onStarted(ServerConnector<SocketConnection> pServerConnector) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connected To :" + pServerConnector.getConnection().getSocket().getInetAddress().getHostAddress().toString());

}
```

**And**

```
// Listener - In the event of a client connecting
    @Override
    public void onStarted(ClientConnector<SocketConnection> pClientConnector) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Client Connected From : " + pClientConnector.getConnection().getSocket().getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at Volley http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html. Of course, you'll also need some server functionality to provide the data. The literature about REST services might be a good start for that task.

Comment: Tnx But its About AndEngine (2D Game Engine For Android) , And Socket Programming on Local Network , So i Dont Think Volly Can Help !

Answer (score 0):

This Can Help , But Need Some Change :

```
    // Listener - In the event of a client connecting
    @Override
    public void onStarted(ClientConnector<SocketConnection> pClientConnector) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Client Connected From : " + pClientConnector.getConnection().getSocket().getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
        String clientIp = pClientConnector.getConnection().getSocket().getInetAddress().getHostAddress().toString();

        if (MultiplayerExtensionBaseGame.mClient != null) {
            MultiplayerExtensionBaseGame.heroType = ++MultiplayerExtensionBaseGame.heroType;
            Log.i("HTI", "" + MultiplayerExtensionBaseGame.heroType);
        }

        if (MultiplayerExtensionBaseGame.mClient != null) {
            AddSpriteClientMessage message = (AddSpriteClientMessage) MultiplayerExtensionBaseGame.mMessagePool.obtainMessage(ClientMessages.CLIENT_MESSAGE_ADD_SPRITE);
            message.set(MultiplayerExtensionBaseGame.CLIENT_ID, mEngine.getCamera().getCenterX() - 250, mEngine.getCamera().getHeight() - (50 * MultiplayerExtensionBaseGame.heroType),
                    MultiplayerExtensionBaseGame.heroType);


MultiplayerExtensionBaseGame.mClient.sendMessage(message);
        MultiplayerExtensionBaseGame.mMessagePool.recycleMessage(message);
    }
}
```

**And Then**

```
 int type = message.getSpriteType();

                        switch (type) {
                            case 1:
                                AnimatedSprite sBox = new AnimatedSprite(message.getX(), message.getY(), MultiplayerExtensionBaseGame.rBox, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                                sBox.setUserData("ServerHero");
                                sBox.animate(150);
                                mScene.attachChild(sBox);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                AnimatedSprite sCircle = new AnimatedSprite(message.getX(), message.getY(), MultiplayerExtensionBaseGame.rCircle, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                                sCircle.setUserData("ClientHero_1");
                                sCircle.animate(150);
                                mScene.attachChild(sCircle);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                AnimatedSprite sTriangle = new AnimatedSprite(message.getX(), message.getY(), MultiplayerExtensionBaseGame.rTriangle, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                                sTriangle.setUserData("ClientHero_2");
                                sTriangle.animate(150);
                                mScene.attachChild(sTriangle);
                                break;
                        }
```